# Rich text editor in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have create rich text editor in react and it is working fine too but i want to pass this value in other component and store it in state, can anyone suggest me the right way.
This is rich text content component, which is working fine.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { EditorState } from "draft-js";
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import { convertToHTML } from "draft-convert";
import DOMPurify from "dompurify";
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
import style from "./RichText.module.css";
const App = () => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() =>
    EditorState.createEmpty()
  );
  const [convertedContent, setConvertedContent] = useState(null);
  const handleEditorChange = (state) => {
    setEditorState(state);
    convertContentToHTML();
  };
  const convertContentToHTML = () => {
    let currentContentAsHTML = convertToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent());
    setConvertedContent(currentContentAsHTML);
  };
  const createMarkup = (html) => {
    return {
      __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(html),
    };
  };
  return (
    <div className={style.App}>
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange}
        wrapperClassName={style.wrapperClass}
        editorClassName={style.editorClass}
        toolbarClassName={style.toolbarClass}
      />
      <div
        className={style.preview}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(convertedContent)}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

and in other component i want to get data in setPostBody useState -

```
const [postBody, setpostBody] = useState("");
<RichText />
```

link - https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-gauss-pq2wr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: can you share complete code for other component where you want to get data

Comment: there are three different ways to achieve this solution
1. using props
2. context
3. redux

right now I can't tell anything from the code you shared

Comment: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-gauss-pq2wr?file=/src/Modal.js)

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: project is not working some files are missing

Comment: I did some changes to give you an idea [Codebox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-torvalds-18zxwp?file=/src/CreateBlog.js:1974-1985)